# Is there a Ruby CSV parser that generates column getter methods?

Tags: ruby, csv, fastercsv

I'm trying to generalize a data retrieval mechanism with Ruby, and can't seem to find a way to retrieve a CSV file and access one of the row's columns by using a dot operator like so:

Let's say I have a CSV table:

```
#some_file.csv
name,age
albert,13
```

And I create a FasterCSV table from it:

```
a = FasterCSV.new(File.open('some_file.csv'), :headers => :first_row)
```

Then, when accessing a row, I'd like to be able to say:

```
a[0].name
=> 'albert'
```

Instead of

```
a[0]['name']
=> 'albert'
```

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Completely independent of FasterCSV, you can always use the header row to create a hash that maps names to indices and use that hash to index the table using something like `a[0][cols(:name)]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you don't find one, you can always monkey-patch `FasterCSV::Row` class, something like:

```
class FasterCSV::Row
  def method_missing(m,*args)
    if self.field?(m.to_s)
      return self[m.to_s]
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

(Haven't tried the code myself.)

PS. As you are generalizing data retrieval mechanism, I assume that CSV is just one of several data sources you plan to support. The logical thing then would be to create a single wrapper class for each of your data sources, with some common interface (which might or might not use accessors for accessing row fields). But underneath it should still access CSV row usual way, using `[]` method. So, as Glenjamin already asked, why do you need this at all? ;)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer would be.. why?

I'll assume its mostly as syntactic sugar, so here's a little monkeypatch that should do what it is you want:

```
class FasterCSV::Row
  def method_missing(row)
    field(row)
  end
end
```

Note that any field names conflicting with existing Row methods wont work like this.